# Delayed_job with twilio 'undefined method 'perform'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying to use the delayed_job gem to delay when a text message is sent out. The sent_text_message method is the method which actually sends the text message, which I am trying to perform at a delayed time. When I run the code I get an error of "undefined method `perform'". If I remove the self from both instances where it appears, I get an error of 'Cannot enqueue items which do not respond to perform'. Can anyone help?

```
  def schedule_sending_text
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(self.perform, :run_at => @reminder.time)
  end

  def self.perform
    send_text_message
  end
```

Comment: You might need to restart the worker processes using

rake jobs:work

Comment: Do you have your preform methods in their respective job class?